# An equivalence of AC

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have to prove the following:

In $ZF^-$ the axiom of choice implies:

For every set X there exist $Y \subseteq \bigcup X$ such that:

- Y has at most one element in common with each of X
- Y is maximal with respect to the previous property among the subset of X

I'll try to solve it using the Zorn's Lemma (that are equivalent to AC) but I can't see the way to solve it.

Thanks for the attention!

Comment: Hint: Choose things.

Comment: Could you try to write the question better? Do you have a collection of sets $X_i$? The notation $\cup X$ does not mean anything if you have only one set $X$.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: $\bigcup X$ is a well-defined notion. It's the union of all the elements of $X$.

Comment: By the way, andreasvr, to argue that this is equivalent to $\sf AC$, you need to argue the other direction as well. Also, what exactly do you mean by $\sf ZF^-$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have never seen this. If it is the union of elements of $X$, then for me it is equal to $X$. Probably I am not understanding something easy, sorry for this.

Comment: @Jeremy: It's a standard notation in set theory. $\bigcup X=\{y\mid\exists x\in X: y\in x\}$. It's not necessarily $X$ itself, note that the elements of $X$ are not the singletons of the elements of $X$.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the explanation. I get it now. So $X$ is a set of sets. I find it a bit confusing, but if it is standard, I cannot be against it... :-)

Comment: @Jeremy: In set theory, everything is a set. Every set is a set of sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila For me $ZF^{-}$ are the axiom of Zermelo-Frenkel without the axiom of choice and the axiom of Foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a partial order of all subsets of $\bigcup X$ which meet every element of $X$ at most in a single point, and order those by inclusion.

Suppose that $\{Y_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a chain in this partial order, then $Y=\bigcup\{Y_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a subset of $\bigcup X$ (trivial) and if $x\in X$ then $x\in Y=\bigcup(Y_i\cap x)$. Suppose by contradiction that $|x\cap Y|>1$, then there is some $Y_i,Y_j$ such that $x\cap Y_i\neq x\cap Y_j$, but neither is empty.

However, since this is a chain, $Y_i\subseteq Y_j$ or $Y_j\subseteq Y_i$. This means that there is some $i\in I$ such that $x\cap Y_i$ has more than a single point. This is impossible because $Y_i$'s are assumed to be taken from our partial order. Therefore $x\cap Y$ has at most one point.

Therefore from Zorn's lemma there exists a maximal $Y$ in this partial order, which is what we were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only one more clarification : it's trivial that there exists a subset of $\bigcup X$ which meet every element of X at most in a single point?

Comment: Maybe it can be the original set X? if you don't prove that Y isn't empty you can't apply Zorn's Lemma!!

Comment: For the first comment, I'm not sure if it's trivial. It's not hard to produce a model where the axiom of choice fails and this principle fails as well (and the title of your question says it's in fact equivalent to the axiom...); as for the second comment note that $Y$ is not the partial order we apply Zorn's lemma for, I didn't assign a letter to that partial order, but it's not empty. The empty set and singletons (from $\bigcup X$), they satisfy the wanted property, so at least they must be there (and if all the elements of $X$ has a non-empty intersection, then a singleton can be maximal).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, this calls for Zorn. I think the idea should be straightforward, but maybe we should really spell it out:

Let $$\mathcal Y=\{\,Y\in\mathcal P(\bigcup X)\mid\forall Z\in X\colon \forall U,V\in Z\cap Y\colon U=V\,\}$$
Then $\mathcal Y$ is partially ordered by inclusion. If $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal Y$ is a chain, then $C=\bigcup \mathcal C$ is an upper bound for $\mathcal C$.
Indeed, clearly $C\subseteq \bigcup X$ and $Y\subseteq C$ for all $Y\in \mathcal C$; 
and if $Z\in X$ and  $U\in Z\cap C$, then $U\in Z\cap Y_U$ for some $Y_U\in \mathcal C$. Similarly, if $V\in Z\cap C$, then $U\in Z\cap Y_V$ for some $Y_V\in \mathcal C$. As $\mathcal C$ is a chain we have wlog $Y_U\subseteq Y_V$, hence $U,V\in Z\cap Y_V$ and so $U=V$.
Zorn's lemma then says that $\mathcal Y$ has a maximal element.

Comment: To applying correctly the Zorn's Lemma you have firstly to show that the set that you are considering isn't empty. How can I argue to solve this?

Comment: Maybe X itself is contained in Y? Are you agree?